# Consulta com MAX(DATE)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Estou tentando gerar a consulta abaixo da seguinte forma.

> ```
> Cliente     Tarefa  Data da Ultima Providencia
> Teste        16555       04-07-2017
> ```

Porém, está gerando de forma duplicada, ou seja, quero pegar a ultima data da ultima providencia, porém, está trazendo todas as datas mesmo utilizando o `max`.

> ```
> Cliente     Tarefa  Data da Ultima Providencia
> Teste        16555       04-07-2017 
> Teste        16555       02-06-2017
> ```

```
SELECT uc.usurazaosocial [cliente - razão social],
       uc.usunome [cliente - nome fantasia],
       t.tarid [tarefa],
       ur.usunome [responsável - tarefa],
       t.tartitulo [título],
       MAX(CONVERT(date, a.ativdata, 103))[data última providência],
       ISNULL(uta.usunome, utg.usunome) [responsável tramite],
       dbo.dias_uteis(MAX(CONVERT(date, a.ativdata, 103)), GETDATE()) [dias sem movimentação],
       t.tarnumativ [número da providência],
       s.statusdesc [status]
  FROM tarefa t
       LEFT JOIN usuario uc ON uc.usuid = t.usuidcliente
       LEFT JOIN usuario ur ON ur.usuid = t.usuidresponsavel
       LEFT JOIN atividade a ON a.tarid = t.tarid
       LEFT JOIN usuario uta ON uta.usuid = a.usuidalteracao
       LEFT JOIN usuario utg ON utg.usuid = a.usuid
       LEFT JOIN status s ON s.codstatus = t.tarstatus
 WHERE t.projid IS NOT NULL
   AND a.ativorigem = 'S'
   AND t.tarid = 161574
 GROUP BY uc.usurazaosocial,
          uc.usunome,
          t.tarid,
          t.tartitulo,
          t.tarnumativ,
          s.statusdesc,
          ur.usunome,
          uta.usunome,
          utg.usunome
 ORDER BY uc.usurazaosocial DESC
```

Comment: Duplicado da onde? Recomendado [tour].

Comment: Mas você está retornando muito mais campos do que os 3 que você cita.

Comment: @Stormwind, a tarefa está duplicado, era para trazer somente a data máxima.

Comment: @Sorack, coloquei esses tres campos na pergunta só demonstrativo. Os outros campos estão com o mesmo valor, o que difere é somente a data que no caso era pra trazer somente o primeiro registro com a data máxima.

Comment: Bota um `DISTINCT` logo depois do `SELECT` e o `MAX` na data para testar.

Comment: já tinha feito esse teste @Sorack, mas nao funcionou

Comment: Qual a chave primária da tabela `atividade`?

Comment: @Sorack, é o campo AtivID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifique sua `query`. Utilize `NOT EXISTS` para verificar se é a última data:

```
SELECT uc.usurazaosocial AS razao_social,
       uc.usunome AS nome_fantasia,
       t.tarid AS tarefa,
       CONVERT(date, a.ativdata, 103) AS ultima_providencia
  FROM tarefa t
       INNER JOIN atividade a ON a.tarid = t.tarid
       LEFT JOIN usuario uc ON uc.usuid = t.usuidcliente
 WHERE t.projid IS NOT NULL
   AND a.ativorigem = 'S'
   AND t.tarid = 161574
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM atividade a2
                   WHERE a2.tarid = a.tarid
                     AND a2.ativdata > a.ativdata)
```

Comment: Verdade @Sorack, nao tinha pensado na possibilidade do not exists.